# upgrade Ninject v2 to v3 with .NET 4 System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, ninject, ninject.web.mvc, ninject-3

I am attempting to use Ninject v3 to test a web service hosted within a .NET4 windows service ( `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase` ).

I create `MyServerModule : NinjectModule` , and within `Load()` I conditionally bind my interfaces to runtime objects based on `app.config` settings.

In `ServiceBase.OnStart()`, the init steps are : First, create a new `StandardKernel` based on an instance of `MyServerModule` and associate it with Ninject container.  Next, create an instance of `NinjectServiceHost` based on my service class, and open the service host to begin listening.

In Ninject v2, the code is :

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyServerModule());
KernelContainer.Kernel = kernel; 
NinjectServiceHost serviceHost = new NinjectServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
serviceHost.Open();
```

However, in Ninject v3, `KernelContainer` no longer exists.  Additionally, `NinjectServiceHost()` now accepts a server factory that subclasses `IServiceBehavior`.

How do I perform similar initialization steps in Ninject v3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue running several self-hosted WCF services within a Windows Service.  I ended up using `kernel.Get<IServiceBehavior>()` as the first parameter when initializing each NinjectServiceHost.

Your example might look like:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyServerModule());
NinjectServiceHost serviceHost = new NinjectServiceHost( kernel.Get<IServiceBehavior>(), typeof(MyService));
serviceHost.Open();
```